# Data guard - READ WRITE & READ ONLY issue

Tags: oracle11g, dataguard

Yesterday I made my physical standby database to primary (manually) and opened the database in READ WRITE mode. Because my primary database server crashed due to h/w issue and user requested me to open the database in READ WRITE mode and I did.

Now I want to change the role back to PHYSICAL STANDBY as my actual primary database is up and running now.

**Can I do it? Or do I need to rebuild entire data guard set up?**

version: Oracle 11g

Below are the steps I executed on standby to make phy_standby to primary.

```
SQL> alter database recover managed standby database cancel;

SQL> alter database activate physical standby database;
```

Comment: "Oracle 11g" is a bit vague. There are about 7 different versions that qualify as "Oracle 11g". You should add the exact version (e.g. 11.2.0.4) to your question.

Comment: Sorry friend. its 11.2.0.3 and this standby has no FLASHBACK enabled. Is there any way i can get what was the scn at that time on standby open in READ WRITE mode?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in one of your comments that flashback database was not enabled before the failover occurred, you'll have to rebuild your standby environment:

From the Oracle 11.2 [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/scenarios.htm#SBYDB00910):

> After a failover occurs, the original primary database can no longer
>   participate in the Data Guard configuration until it is repaired and
>   established as a standby database in the new configuration. To do
>   this, you can use the Flashback Database feature to recover the failed
>   primary database to a point in time before the failover occurred, and
>   then convert it into a physical or logical standby database in the new
>   configuration.